# SVG images on Android 2.3.x and iOS7 with intel XDK

Tags: ios7, svg, android-2.3-gingerbread, intel-xdk

We have chosen to build our next app with the XDK, for both android and iOS. Our question is:

Are SVG images working on Android 2.3.x and iOS7 devices (not emulators or simulators) through the use of the intel XDK?

Can anyone confirm real-life experience regarding this ?

Thanks!

Please reply to the post at the intel xdk forum:
https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=6613

Answer (score 1):

Full support for SVGs began in iOS 3.2 and Android 3.0. [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/svg) is a great resource for viewing when HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more are supported on mobile operating systems.